# Pick a random value from a bag

Tags: apache-pig

Have grouped data in the relation B in the format

```
1, {(1,abc), (1,def)}
2, {(2,ghi), (2,mno), (2,pqr)}
```

Now I wan to pick a random value from the bag and I want the output like

```
1, abc
2, mno
```

In case we picked up like first tuple for 1 or second tuple for 2

The issue is I have only grouped data B;

```
DESCRIBE B
B: {group: int,A: {(id: int,min: chararray,fan: chararray,max: chararray)}}
```

If I try to flatten it by

```
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN($1)
DESCRIBE C;
C: {A::id: int,A::min: chararray,A::fan: chararray,A::max: chararray}
```

Then I try to do

```
rand =
    FOREACH B {
        shuf_ = FOREACH C GENERATE RANDOM() AS r, *;  line L
        shuf = ORDER shuf_ BY r;
        pick1 = LIMIT shuf 1;
    GENERATE
        group,
        FLATTEN(pick1);
    };
```

I get an error at line L an error at this point "Pig script failed to parse: expression is not a project expression: (Name: ScalarExpression) Type: null Uid: null)"

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus : Any comments on this one ?

Answer (score 1):

You cant refer to C when doing a `FOREACH` on B. Because C is built from B. You need to use projection that B is built from , i.e A

Looking at your describe schemas
    B: {group: int,A: {(id: int,min: chararray,fan: chararray,max: chararray)}}

Why cant you to use A, as it will work

Comment: I dont have A with me anymore. I get B after doing some Random SPLIT where I have filtered a lot of records. So, I dont have the precise A from which B is built. As of now, I am working this out by rebuilding B from C again . Any better approaches ?